# RCP open editors parallel

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I've got a problem opening multiple editors within a RCP Application. As I know there is only one `UI-Thread` painting the GUI.

In my use case I have to open about 50 editors the same time and that takes some time because of blocking the UI Thread until all editors are opened. The loading of the data within my editors is done with Jobs.

I try searching if there is some mechanism to parallize the opening to not block the UI Thread, but didn't find anything. Is there any possibility to do this? It would be very helpful if each editor is opend/painted within an own UI-Thread, so that a user can already work with the opended Editors.

Comment: @Floradu88 Please stop editing in random "Code highlighting" for words that are not code. I am removing these edits and rejecting new ones I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have already answered your question - there is only one UI-Thread in Eclipse-RCP application. You might want to reconsider you application design and use lazy loading mechanism where possible (comboboxes, viewers etc.), or try to find some places, where data loading takes more time and could be optimized, but visual initialization of editors will still take some time, especially if you are opening multiple editors simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you. Then the use case must be adapted but that should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is use `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditors(IWorkbenchPage, IFile[])` in an IDE product or 'org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage.openEditors(IEditorInput[], String[], int)' in an RCP product to defer the cost of opening the editors.  Both methods are available as of Eclipse 3.5.

It creates all of the tabs for the editors as requested, but it only materializes the editor that ends up being active.  It provides the same behaviour as if the user closed down and re-opened eclipse with many editors open (only materializing the visible editor).

See the javadoc for IWorkbenchPage for more information, http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIWorkbenchPage.html

PW

Comment: Sounds useful. Is this method available in Eclipse 3.6? I didn't find any API therefor. Can you provide some link?